# What is Func, how and when is it used

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

What is `Func<>` and what is it used for?

Comment: It's just a shortcut for delegates with a specific signature. To fully understand the answers below you'll need to understand delegates ;-)

Comment: In the answer of @Oded it says `If you have a function that needs to return different types, depending on the parameters, you can use a Func delegate, specifying the return type.`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`Func<T>` is a predefined delegate type for a method that returns some value of the type `T`.

In other words, you can use this type to reference a method that returns some value of `T`. E.g.

```
public static string GetMessage() { return "Hello world"; }
```

may be referenced like this

```
Func<string> f = GetMessage;
```

Comment: But it can also represent a static one-argument function =)

Comment: @Ark-kun no, that's not correct. The definition of `Func<T>` is `delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()`. No arguments. `Func<T1, T2>` would be a function that takes one argument.

Comment: No, I'm correct. `static int OneArgFunc(this string i) { return 42; }` `Func<int> f = "foo".OneArgFunc;`. =)

Comment: That's an extension method which is special.

Comment: The only special thing about it is the `Extension` attribute which is only read by the C#/VB.Net compilers, not CLR. Basically, instance methods (unlike static functions) have a hidden 0th "this" parameter. So, 1-argument instance method is very similar to 2-argument static function. Then, we have delegates which store *target* object and *function pointer*. Delegates can store the first argument in *target* or not do that.

Comment: Okay, let me put is this way then: A reference of the type `Func<int>` cannot point to `public static int F(int i) { return 0; }` which is a static one-argument function. You need `Func<int, int>` for that.

Comment: The trick only works for reference types, so let's use `string` argument instead of `int`. `Func<int>` **can** point to `public static int F(string s) { return 0; }`. As I've said, there is nothing special about extension methods (at the IL level). The IL code that creates a `Func<int>` instance from the function is valid regardless of the function's attributes. (But I must say I didn't believe my own eyes when I saw the compiler doing that.)

Comment: All in all, there are 2x2=4 different situations: (instance function or static function) x (using *target* or not using *target*). Common cases are: "instance function; using *target*" and "static function; not using *target*". But other two cases are possible too. "static function; using *target*" is the extension method example that I've shown. And "instance function; not using *target*" is called an *open instance method delegate* and is somewhat opposite to the concept of the extension method.

Comment: Speaking of the 4th situation (open instance method delegates): it's possible to create a `Func<MyClass, string>` delegate form an instance method like `class MyClass { public string MyMethod() { return ""; } }`.

Comment: Well, despite what you're saying `public static int F(string s) { return 0; }` and `Func<int> f = F;` will not compile.

Comment: It doesn't work because you don't provide the string argument. But as I've said, yes, with C#/VB.Net compilers the static method must be marked as `Extension` for this to work. But **on the IL level** there is no difference between extension methods and static methods. You can write `public static int StaticF(string s) { return 1; }` `public static int ExtensionF(this string s) { return 2; }` `Func<int> f = "a".ExtensionF;`, compile it, then replace `ExtensionF` with `StaticF` **in the IL** and it will work just fine.

Comment: The point here is that this is not an IL issue. The compiler cannot bind the reference because the types do not match.

Comment: Yes. The C# compiler can only bind the delegate construction call to a method group when the signature of the method's free parameters matches the delegate signature. The C# compiler thus allows binding the extension method to `Func<int>` or `Func<string, int>` depending on the syntax used ("instance" call syntax or "static" call syntax) (which affects the number of free parameters and the free parameters signature).

Comment: Good discussion. After 4 years what would both of you add to this?

Comment: And, for the sake of your team mates, never use this abstracted garbage.  Just write out the code explicitly.  you got two hands, hopefully.

Answer (score 110):

Think of it as a placeholder. It can be quite useful when you have code that follows a certain pattern but need not be tied to any particular functionality.

For example, consider the `Enumerable.Select` extension method.

- The *pattern* is: for every item in a sequence, select some value from that item (e.g., a property) and create a new sequence consisting of these values.
- The *placeholder* is: some selector function that actually gets the values for the sequence described above.

This method takes a `Func<T, TResult>` instead of any concrete function. This allows it to be used in *any* context where the above pattern applies.

So for example, say I have a `List<Person>` and I want just the name of every person in the list. I can do this:

```
var names = people.Select(p => p.Name);
```

Or say I want the *age* of every person:

```
var ages = people.Select(p => p.Age);
```

Right away, you can see how I was able to leverage the *same* code representing a *pattern* (with `Select`) with two *different* functions (`p => p.Name` and `p => p.Age`).

The alternative would be to write a different version of `Select` every time you wanted to scan a sequence for a different kind of value. So to achieve the same effect as above, I would need:

```
// Presumably, the code inside these two methods would look almost identical;
// the only difference would be the part that actually selects a value
// based on a Person.
var names = GetPersonNames(people);
var ages = GetPersonAges(people);
```

With a delegate acting as placeholder, I free myself from having to write out the same pattern over and over in cases like this.

Answer (score 75):

`Func<T1, T2, ..., Tn, Tr>`  represents a function, that takes (T1, T2, ..., Tn) arguments and returns Tr.

For example, if you have a function:

```
double sqr(double x) { return x * x; }
```

You could save it as some kind of a function-variable:

```
Func<double, double> f1 = sqr;
Func<double, double> f2 = x => x * x;
```

And then use exactly as you would use sqr:

```
f1(2);
Console.WriteLine(f2(f1(4)));
```

etc.

Remember though, that it's a delegate, for more advanced info refer to documentation.

Comment: Excelent answer, but for compilling keyword static is neeed

Answer (score 25):

I find `Func<T>` very useful when I create a component that needs to be personalized "on the fly".

Take this very simple example: a `PrintListToConsole<T>` component.

A very simple object that prints this list of objects to the console.
You want to let the developer that uses it personalize the output.

For example, you want to let him define a particular type of number format and so on.

**Without Func**

First, you have to create an interface for a class that takes the input and produces the string to print to the console.

```
interface PrintListConsoleRender<T> {
  String Render(T input);
}
```

Then you have to create the class `PrintListToConsole<T>` that takes the previously created interface and uses it over each element of the list.

```
class PrintListToConsole<T> {

    private PrintListConsoleRender<T> _renderer;

    public void SetRenderer(PrintListConsoleRender<T> r) {
        // this is the point where I can personalize the render mechanism
        _renderer = r;
    }

    public void PrintToConsole(List<T> list) {
        foreach (var item in list) {
            Console.Write(_renderer.Render(item));
        }
    }   
}
```

The developer that needs to use your component has to:

1. implement the interface
2. pass the real class to the `PrintListToConsole`

   ```
   class MyRenderer : PrintListConsoleRender<int> {
       public String Render(int input) {
           return "Number: " + input;
       }
   }

   class Program {
       static void Main(string[] args) {
           var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
           var printer = new PrintListToConsole<int>();
           printer.SetRenderer(new MyRenderer());
           printer.PrintToConsole(list);
           string result = Console.ReadLine();   
       }   
   }
   ```

**Using Func it's much simpler**

Inside the component you define a parameter of type `Func<T,String>` that **represents an interface of a function** that takes an input parameter of type T and returns a string (the output for the console)

```
class PrintListToConsole<T> {

    private Func<T, String> _renderFunc;

    public void SetRenderFunc(Func<T, String> r) {
        // this is the point where I can set the render mechanism
        _renderFunc = r;
    }

    public void Print(List<T> list) {
        foreach (var item in list) {
            Console.Write(_renderFunc(item));
        }
    }
}
```

When the developer uses your component he simply passes to the component the implementation of the `Func<T, String>` type, that is a function that creates the output for the console.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }; // should be a list as the method signature expects
        var printer = new PrintListToConsole<int>();
        printer.SetRenderFunc((o) => "Number:" + o);
        printer.Print(list); 
        string result = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**`Func<T>` lets you define a generic method interface on the fly.**
You define what type the input is and what type the output is.
Simple and concise.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Marco. It has really helped me. I have been trying to understand func for a while and also actively use it in my programming. This example will clear the path. I had to add the StampaFunc method as that was left out in the original code which prevented it from displaying.

Comment: I think there is a line missed in Func sample, Where is the call for print function or StampaFunc ?

Answer (score 10):

`Func<T1,R>` and the other predefined generic `Func` delegates (`Func<T1,T2,R>`, `Func<T1,T2,T3,R>` and others) are generic delegates that return the type of the last generic parameter.

If you have a function that needs to return different types, depending on the parameters, you can use a `Func` delegate, specifying the return type.

Answer (score 9):

It is just a predefined generic delegate. Using it you don't need to declare every delegate. There is another predefined delegate, `Action<T, T2...>`, which is the same but returns void.

Answer (score 2):

Both C# and Java don't have plain functions only member functions (aka methods). And the methods are not first-class citizens. First-class functions allow us to create beautiful and powerful code, as seen in F# or Clojure languages. (For instance, first-class functions can be passed as parameters and can return functions.)  Java and C# ameliorate this somewhat with interfaces/delegates.

```
Func<int, int, int> randInt = (n1, n2) => new Random().Next(n1, n2);
```

So, `Func` is a built-in delegate which brings some functional programming features and helps reduce code verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not too late to add some info.

**Sum:**

The Func is a custom delegate defined in System namespace that allows you to point to a method with the same signature (as delegates do), using 0 to 16 input parameters and that must return something.

**Nomenclature & how2use:**

```
Func<input_1, input_2, ..., input1_6, output> funcDelegate = someMethod;
```

**Definition:**

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

**Where it is used:**

It is  used in lambda expressions and anonymous methods.

Answer (score 0):

Aforementioned answers are great, just putting few points I see might be helpful:

- Func is built-in delegate type
- Func delegate type must return a value. Use [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0) delegate if no return type needed.
- Func delegate type can have zero to 16 input parameters.
- Func delegate does not allow ref and out parameters.
- Func delegate type can be used with an anonymous method or lambda expression.

  Func<int, int, int>  Sum  = (x, y) => x + y;