# Can I test a single object against a LINQ function?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ function similar to the one below:

```
public static Func<Contact, bool> activeContactsFilter = c =>
    !c.suspended &&
    !c.expired &&
    (c.status_id == 1 || c.status_id == 7);
```

This works great when I need to find out which Contacts amongst an `IEnumerable` of contacts are "active":

```
var activeContacts = allContacts.Where(activeContactsFilter);
```

But what if I want to just check if ONE specific contact is "active"? How do I use this same function for a test on a single object?

Comment: Have you tried just calling it `activeContactsFilter(contact1)`?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "LINQ" function.

Comment: @jon `Select`, `Where`, `GroupBy`... :D

Comment: @Rawling: Well... those are *methods*... ;-)

Comment: @jon [... OK you win.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: @Jon Emmmm, I'm pretty sure they are *functions* actually (unless I have a very messed up definition for what a function and a method is, which is entirely possible of course)

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: We were not being serious.

Comment: @Jon oh, that wen't way over my head :P Really hard to detect sarcasm on the net, sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple - just call the `Func` like it was, well, a function:

```
bool contactIsActive = activeContactsFilter(contactToCheck);
```

`Func`s aren't specifically LINQ-related, they're just *useful* for LINQ. You can store a method in a `Func` of the correct type, and (as above) you can call a `Func` like a method.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624731/what-is-func-how-and-when-is-it-used) for more information on `Func`s.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer (also @BartoszKP) - will accept as soon as I'm allowed to by SO.