# Convert/Parse many Objects using a member Method with less Code

Tags: c#, linq, readability

Is there any simple way to convert/parse many Objects of Class `Foo` to objects of class `Bar`, using a member method of class `Bar` like `Bar.loadFromFooObject(Foo classFoo)` ?

So if I have those 2 Classes:

```
class Foo
{
   public string var1;
   public int var2;
   public List<string> var3;
}

class Bar
{
   public string var1;
   public int var2;
   public float var4;

   public void loadFromFooObject(Foo fooObj)
   {
      this.var1 = fooObj.var1;
      this.var2 = fooObj.var2;
   }
}
```

So that I can avoid doing:

```
Foo[] fooObjs = { new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo()};
Bar[] barObjs = new Bar[fooObjs.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < fooObjs.Length; i++)
{
   barObjs[i].loadFromFooObject(fooObjs[i]);
}
```

And do something like:

```
Foo[] fooObjs = { new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo()};
Bar[] barObjs = fooObjs.Parse(loadFromFooObject);
```

Is something like this possible using C# and/or Linq?

Comment: Your code could be pseudo-code but `barObjs[i].loadFromFooObject`   would raise a NRE. You can *probably* have a static method in your class `Bar` and call that to transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this strategy a lot for any kind of object conversion/mapping:

- Create the function for a single object conversion
- Create an overload accepting an `IEnumerable` (usually a List for me) and use LINQ [`.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to convert the entire list into.  It codes seamlessly since the single object conversion is, by definition, a [`Func`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624731/what-is-func-how-and-when-is-it-used/3624782#3624782) for more explanation on `Func`s.

You can also get fancy with extension methods by creating a few extension methods in a static class.  For you case specifically, the extension methods could look like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Bar ToBar(this Foo foo)
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        bar.loadFromFooObject(foo);
        //you could also move the logic to convert from the Bar class in here
        return bar;
    }

    //Overload for a collection of Foos (like Foo[] or List<Foo>)
    public static IEnumerable<Bar> ToBars(this IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        //Since ToBar is a Func<Foo, Bar>
        return foos.Select(ToBar);
        //alternate lambda syntax:  return foos.Select(foo => foo.ToBar());
    }
}
```

And you would call these methods like this:

```
var fooList = new List<Foo>();
var barEnumerable = fooList.ToBars();
```

Comment: This in my opinion is a neat way to do it. Looks super clean in the code! Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Write a method `TransformFooToBar` and then use the linq, e.g.,

```
var barObjs = fooObjs.Select(n => TransformFooToBar(n)).ToArray();
```

If you really want it to be a method on the `Bar` class, write an extension method, and then linq looks like this:

```
var barObjs = fooObjs.Select(n => n.TransformFooToBar()).ToArray();
```

Comment: You could even go one step further and write an overloaded extension method to extend the `IEnumerable<Foo>` itself to call the above LINQ select statement.  It would look like `var barObjs = fooObjs.TransformFoosToBars();`

Comment: It should be mentioned that if it's left as a static method, the first version can be written slightly more simply as: `fooObjs.Select( TransformFooToBar ).ToArray()`.  Naturally if it's an extension method this will also work (provided the static class name is included).

Comment: @ryanyuyu This seems to be interesting. Could you show that approach in an answer maybe? :)

Answer (score 1):

This something like this, all you need to create a ConvertToBar method which takes a Foo and returns a Bar.

```
var barObjs = fooObjs.Select(i=>ConvertToBar(i)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Create the ConvertToBar Method in which context?

Comment: I don't think it belongs to either object. Create it in a factory class.

Answer (score 0):

My preference (and it is just a personal preference) is to override the explicit cast operator and just cast from one type to the other. Combine that with Kye's answer to handle multiple objects.