# Define part of an Expression as a variable in c#

Tags: c#, expression

I have following code:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
   Expression<Func<T,bool>> Criteria {get; set;}
}
public class Customer
{
   //..
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and use it as following:

```
var c = new MyClass<Customer>();
c.Criteria = x.Name.StartWith("SomeTexts");
```

Is there any way to define something like this:

```
? p = x=>x.Customer.Name;
var c = new MyClass<Customer>();
c.Criteria = p => p.StartWith("SomeTexts");
```

I used `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to use it as where clause in my `linq to entities` query (EF code first).

Comment: Is `p` an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` or a `Func<T, bool>`?

Comment: Shouldn't `c.Criteria = x.Name.StartWith("SomeTexts");` be `c.Criteria = x => x.Name.StartWith("SomeTexts");`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: you are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following helper functions (one could probably give them a better names, but that's not essential):

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<TOuter, TResult>> Bind<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(this Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner>> source, Expression<Func<TInner, TResult>> resultSelector)
    {
        var body = new ParameterExpressionReplacer { source = resultSelector.Parameters[0], target = source.Body }.Visit(resultSelector.Body);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TOuter, TResult>>(body, source.Parameters);
        return lambda;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TOuter, TResult>> ApplyTo<TInner, TResult, TOuter>(this Expression<Func<TInner, TResult>> source, Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner>> innerSelector)
    {
        return innerSelector.Bind(source);
    }

    class ParameterExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression source;
        public Expression target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == source ? target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Let see how the sample expression

```
c.Criteria = x => x.Name.StartsWith("SomeTexts");
```

can be built from the two different parts.

If you have

```
Expression<Func<Customer, string>> e = x => x.Name;
```

then

```
c.Criteria = e.Bind(x => x.StartsWith("SomeTexts"));
```

or if you have this instead

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> e = x => x.StartsWith("SomeTexts");
```

then

```
c.Criteria = e.ApplyTo((Customer x) => x.Name);
```

If you have both expressions, then you can use any of the two functions, since  `a.Bind(b)` is equivalent to `b.ApplyTo(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

You must define type variable explicit but next code will help you to solve your scenario:

```
// define new expression that get an Order object and returns string value
Expression<Func<Order, string>> p = x => x.Customer.Name;
var c = new MyClass<Order>();

// Compile the expression to the Func then invoke it and call extra criteria
c.Criteria = o => p.Compile().Invoke(o).StartsWith("SomeText");
```

There is little bit simpler solution without expressions:

```
Func<Order, string> p = x => x.Customer.Name;
var c = new MyClass<Order>();
c.Criteria = o => p(o).StartsWith("SomeText");
```

You can also use `Func<>` instead of `Expression<>` in `MyClass`:

```
public MyClass<T>
{
   Func<T,bool> Criteria {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the benefit of using an `Expression` here. How about a straight [`Func`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624731/what-is-func-how-and-when-is-it-used)?

```
public class MyClass<T> 
{
    public Func<T, string, bool> Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

And then...

```
var myCustomer = new MyClass<Customer>
{
    Criteria = (c, s) => c.Name.StartsWith(s)
};

var customer = new Customer { Name = "Bob" };

var x = myCustomer.Criteria(customer, "B");
```

Comment: I want use Expression<Func<T,bool>> as a criteria in my Linq to entitiy query in EF code first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an expression, then you can use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to do the following:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, string>> p = x => x.Name;

var c = new MyClass<Customer>();

c.Criteria = x => p.Invoke(x).StartsWith("asd"); //Reuse p expression

c.Criteria = c.Criteria.Expand();
```

`Invoke` is an extension method provided by LinqKit that helps you to compose expressions easily.

After invoking the `Expand` method, `c.Criteria` would contain an expression that is exactly the same as if you have done this:

```
c.Criteria = x => x.Name.StartsWith("asd");
```