# Is it good practice to use "using" on a new empty DataTable?

Tags: c#, idisposable, using-statement

I've been rewriting some old code so that the `using` statement is used for my DataTables, instead of remembering to `Dispose` each time:

```
using (DataTable dt = BLL.GetDataTable()) {
   foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
     // iteration logic
   }
}
```

However in one particular case, the DataTable content differs based on a variable, so I create the initial DataTable and then assign the value afterwards:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
switch(foo) {
  case bar:
     dt = BLL.GetDataTable(bar);
     break;
  default:
     dt = BLL.GetDataTable();
     break;
}
// iteration logic here
dt.Dispose();
```

Changing this to use `using`, I have:

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
    switch(foo) {
      case bar:
         dt = BLL.GetDataTable(bar);
         break;
      default:
         dt = BLL.GetDataTable();
         break;
    }
    // iteration logic here
}
```

Is that good practice (i.e. creating the `empty` DataTable with a `using` statement)?  I don't know why but it doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: Your last example shouldn't compile and you should get the following error: "Cannot assign to 'dt' because it is a 'using variable'"

Comment: @John I was testing the same (checking which dispose was called). Indeed, you cannot assign a variable used in a using

Comment: It is best practice to use ```using()``` on all disposable objects. As @John stated, your third example will not work. But you can assign your cases to a ```func<>``` and use this in your ```using()```.

Comment: Thank you all kindly.  @Rabban could you please post a `func<>` example for my understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last example, you are only disposing the first DataTable object and not the other that gets assigned.

The `using` statement is just syntactic sugar for `try/finally`. You can instead write your last example like:

```
DataTable dt;
try
{
    switch (foo)
    {
        case bar:
            dt = BLL.GetDataTable(bar);
            break;
        default:
            dt = BLL.GetDataTable();
            break;
    }
}
finally
{
    dt?.Dispose();
}
```

This will ensure your `IDisposable` object is always disposed. It is a bit of a weird example in this case though since I don't see why you'd assign a `DataTable` in the `switch` and then immediately dispose it.

Comment: if BLL.GetDataTable(bar) throw an exception - dt will be null. and  dt.Dispose(); - throw one more exception( "Object reference not set to an instance of an object")

Comment: @Basil But, that will be the same issue with your code once OP calls off to their code to generate the data table in `BLL`.

Comment: Could you please clarify your first sentence *"...not the other that gets assigned"*?  I had assumed that because there's only a single variable, that calling Dispose on that would ensure there's nothing left in memory?

Comment: @EvilDr Imagine `DataTable a = new DataTable(); a = new DataTable(); a.Dispose();` - You've created two DataTable objects, but you've only disposed one of them. With a `using` statement, .NET does stop you building this kind of thing, as I mentioned in the comments :) Note that unassigning an object doesn't delete it from memory. .NET will eventually collect _managed_ memory, but the `Dispose` pattern is mostly used to get rid of _unmanaged_ resources, that the garbage collector doesn't know about.

Comment: Hmm very insightful.  I didn't realise unassigned objects were not automatically removed straight away.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As I stated in the comments, your last example won't work. If you want to do something like that, you could move the DataTable generation into a separate function:

```
public DataTable GetBLLDataTable()
{
    switch(foo)
    {
        case bar:
            return BLL.GetDataTable(bar);
            break;
        default:
            return BLL.GetDataTable();
            break;
    }
}
```

And then use the DataTable returned by this method in your using statement:

```
using (DataTable dt = GetBLLDataTable()) {
    // iteration logic here
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach but similar to that what John said. You can use a `func<>` to set your get method and use this in the `using()`

```
Func<DataTable> func = null;
switch (foo)
{
    case bar:
        func = () => BLL.GetDataTable(bar);
        break;
    default:
        func = () => BLL.GetDataTable();
        break;
 }

 using (var dt = func())
 {
     // iteration logic here
 }
```

Personally i would prefer Johns approach, its a bit more readable. But all do the same, so it's up to you to use what you like most.

Comment: Now we just need someone to answer with a local method :-D

Comment: It's likely for the next hour or so I'll be here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/3624731/792888 (!)

Comment: @John Do not challenge them^^

Comment: @EvilDr It's ok if you not know what a ```func<>``` does, just use one of the other approaches that were posted here. I posted this solution only for completeness.