# PDFSharpCore XImage.FromStream

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdf-generation

I try to save an image, which is in a byte array, in XImage.
However, XImage's Core variant offers me the following methods:

- FromImageSource (ImageSource.IImageSource imageSource)
- FromFile (string path)
- FromStream (Func  stream)

FromFile is out of the question.

FromStream would be eligible.
For this I converted my byte array into a stream:

```
Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream (vars.SignEmployee)
```

But FromStream is expecting

```
Func<Stream>
```

How can I convert my stream to Func < Stream> ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624731/what-is-func-how-and-when-is-it-used

Answer (score 12):

```
Stream.Position = 0; //Fix bug PdfSharpCore - link bellow
XImage image = XImage.FromStream (() => Stream);
```

https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/issues/39