# How to correctly read the method signature of the .Any function in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I really enjoy using the aggregate functions that C# provides such as .Any(), but I struggle to understand what my options are just looking from the method signature:

[image]

Can someone help me better understand the meanings of (Func predicate)? I know that I normally use a lamda fucntion here. But, how that translates back into whatever Func is, I don't understand.

Comment: its a function (method) that takes a string as input and returns bool

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `Func`?

Comment: Yes, yes I did. But often it's helpful to have someone knowledgable about a subject explain it in their own words. A single source of documentation suffers from all kinds of primary effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(extension) bool IEnumerable<string>.Any<string>(Func<string, bool> predicate)(+ 1 overload)
Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

Exceptions:
  ArgumentNullException
```

Means:

- You can call this as an extension method.
- On an `IEnumerable<string>`, that is something you can iterate on that gives you `string`. [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/) is type that holds text.
- The name of the method is `Any`
- It has a type argument, which is set to `string`. You probably can call this on a [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) where `T` is something other than `string`.
- It takes a [`Func<string, bool>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) `predicate`, that is a delegate to a function that takes a `string` as input parameter and returns a `bool`.
- There is another overload of the method, which takes different arguments.
- The method documentation says it "Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition." We can presume it goes over the `IEnumerable<string>` calls the `Func<string, bool>` passing the string from the `IEnumerable<string>` passing each value, and returns whether or not it got `true` for any one of them.
- The method is documented to throw an [`ArgumentNullException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.8), presumubly if you pass a `null`.

If we look online for it, we find in the official documentation [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8). There we can see the other overload and also some examples.

Here is one:

```
Pet[] pets =
        { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8, Vaccinated=true },
          new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4, Vaccinated=false },
          new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1, Vaccinated=false } };

    // Determine whether any pets over age 1 are also unvaccinated.
    bool unvaccinated =
        pets.Any(p => p.Age > 1 && p.Vaccinated == false);
```

We see an array of `Pet`, and we call `Any` on it. Thus, in this case the type argument is `Pet` instead of `string`, given that an array of `Pet` is a thing over which you can iterate and it gives you elements of type `Pet`... I'm saying that an array of `Pet` is an `IEnumerable<Pet>`... and thus we are calling `Any<Pet>`.

We observe that the parameter is a lambda expression: `p => p.Age > 1 && p.Vaccinated == false`

This lambda represents an anonymous function that takes an argument `p`. Since we know that we are using `Any<Pet>`, and we know that `Any<Pet>` wants a delegate to a function that takes a `Pet` and returns `bool`, we know that `p` is a `Pet`.

The anonymous function takes the `Pet` `p` compares the property `Age` with `1` and the property `Vaccinated` with `false`, and return `true` if `Age` is greater than `1` and `Vaccinated` is false.

Looking at the values in the array, we can see that the second item (the one of `Name` `"Boots"`) has `Age` greater than `1` and `Vaccinated` is `false`. Thus, the anonymous function should return `true` for that `Pet`.

And given that `Any` return true if the `predicate` (the anonymous funciton) was `true` for any of the elements, we expect `Any` to return `true` in this case. The description of the example and expected output in the official documentation confirms this.

If we still have the doubt, we can, of course, try running the code: [code on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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). The expected output is "There are unvaccinated animals over age one.".

---

If you want to go one step deeper, you can search the [reference implementation of `Enumerable.Any`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1296).

If you know where to look, you can get the [.NET Core source for Enumerable.Any](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs#L48), *Not guaranteed to stay there, refectoring could put it somewhere else.*

You may also be interested in the documentation about [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

---

See also [What is Func, how and when is it used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3624731/402022).

Answer (score 2):

> But, how that translates back into whatever `Func` is?

Well, first we need to know *what* `Func` is.

Let's see how `Func` is [declared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T,out TResult>(T arg);
```

We can see that `Func` is a delegate. If you don't know what a delegate is, there are wonder pages out there that tell you about them: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates).

How is related to the lambda expression you pass in?

The declaration says that `Func` is a delegate that takes a parameter of type `T`, and returns a `TResult`. From the signature of `Any`, we can see that `T` is `string` while `TResult` is `bool` in this particular case.

This means that you can convert a lambda expression, (or a method group,) that takes a `string` as a parameter and returns `bool` to an instance of `Func<string, bool>`.

Let's say you call `Any` like this:

```
something.Any(x => x.Length > 10)
```

From the parameter type, the compiler infers that the lambda expression must take a `string`, so the type of `x` must be `string`. And the lambda expression must also return a `bool`, which it does, so we're good! The lambda expression is converted to an instance of `Func<string, bool>`.